# Get history of another tty

Tags: linux, command-line-arguments, history, tty

I have a small doubt,

I am working in pts/1 and pts/2 in linux,in common case the history of pts/2 is not available in pts/1(when we type history). Is there any way to get the history of pts/2 in pts/1 with out log-out from the pts/2 session?

Anybody can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you put history into a file, e.g. `history > /tmp/pts2.history.txt`, the answer will be no.

Comment: @SamiLaine ,is there is any other way?

Comment: In this particular case I'm prone to ask you to update the question to include what exactly are you trying to accomplish (I'm sure just reading Bash histories of other users is not the final target here).

Comment: I just want to know, if i gave the credentials of my server to my friend,is there is a way to find what commands are used by my friend in my server at the same time he is in the server. @SamiLaine

Comment: First of all: you should not hand out credentials to a person with whom you don't have complete trust. In case you just want to watch what he/she/it is doing for learning purposes, you can ask him/her/it to fire a terminal multiplexer, e.g. screen or tmux, then attach to the same session and watch what's going on. But that works only if he/she/it actually fires screen/tmux/whatever first and then you share the same session. Google screen and/or tmux and learn about them more.